# Display grouping info across multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I would like to design a rdlc-report with the following table-appearance.

```
Grp1  Grp2  ColA  ColB  
Group title 1 -> merged cells!  
------Group title 2 -> merged cells  
------------Row1A Row1B  
------------Row2A Row2B  
------Group title 3 -> merged cells  
------------Row3A Row3B
```

Is this design possible? I have difficulties merging the group by column with the adjacent columns on the right.

-Victor

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I had to choose row groups instead of column groups in the tablix wizard. After that the column merge worked as I wished.